# After attaching permissions to role still getting false in can() method

Tags: laravel, permissions, laravel-5.1, entrust

I am using entrust to manage roles and permission in my application. I am having trouble to call method `attachPermission()` on user. Then I tried it another way I assigned all permissions to a role. When I sign-in using that user I get `false` for every permission from `can()` method.

I can see all permissions assigned to a role. But even registering a middle-ware or calling method;

`Entrust::routeNeedsPermission('admin/countries*','countries-list', Redirect::to('/admin'));`
Is returning false means redirects me to /admin. I don't know what's wrong with it or It is some kind of compatibility issue with laravel 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Check the solution here :

https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/issues/371

Can method is already used by laravel 5.1

Comment: I have already renamed the method `can as may`. this is not working in my case